# Define basic-security users, passwords and roles in application.yml

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am looking for a way to secure methods with the `@Secured` annotation of Spring Boot. For about 10-15 users, I wouldn't want to connect to a database and obtain the users and their authorities/roles from there but rather store them locally in the profile-specific `application.yml` file. Is there a concept in Spring Boot supporting this idea? All I could find so far works with the basic security actuator (`'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'`) and looks like this:

```
security:
  basic:
    enabled: true
  user:
    name: admin
    password: admin
    role: EXAMPLE
```

However, I'm still able to access a method annotated with     `@RolesAllowed("READ")` even though I would assume that user *admin* shouldn't have access to said method. My SecurityConfiguration looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true)
@Profile("secure")
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();

        http.sessionManagement()
                .sessionFixation()
                .newSession();

        http.csrf().disable();
        http.headers().frameOptions().disable();

    }
}
```

Eventually this might be a different issue but maybe it's important for my own understanding.

I'm wondering how I could specify multiple users with different passwords and different roles in my `application.yml` and annotate methods to ensure only authorized users can access the methods.

Comment: you cannot specify  multiple users in your configuration. You would need to construct something yourself for that.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks, I figured out a pretty simple way to achieve it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It can be achieved with custom `ConfigurationProperties`:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("application")
public class ApplicationClients {

    private final List<ApplicationClient> clients = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<ApplicationClient> getClients() {
        return this.clients;
    }

}

@Getter
@Setter
public class ApplicationClient {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String[] roles;
}

@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ApplicationClients.class)
public class AuthenticationManagerConfig extends
        GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationClients application;

    @Override
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        for (ApplicationClient client : application.getClients()) {
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                    .withUser(client.getUsername()).password(client.getPassword()).roles(client.getRoles());
        }
    }

}
```

and then you can specify the users in your `application.yml`:

```
application:
  clients:
    - username: rw
      password: rw
      roles: READ,WRITE
    - username: r
      password: r
      roles: READ
    - username: w
      password: w
      roles: WRITE
```

don't forget to add `spring-boot-configuration-processor` to your `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
```

### Update April 2018

For **Spring Boot 2.0**, I use the following class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
@ConditionalOnWebApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ApplicationClients.class)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final ApplicationClients application;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to("health")).permitAll()
            .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint()).hasRole("ACTUATOR")
            .antMatchers("/rest/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/soap/**").authenticated()
            .and()
            .cors()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
    }

    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager inMemoryUserDetailsManager() {
        final InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
        log.info("Importing {} clients:", application.getClients().size());

        application.getClients().forEach(client -> {
            manager.createUser(User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username(client.getUsername())
                .password(client.getPassword())
                .roles(client.getRoles())
                .build());
            log.info("Imported client {}", client.toString());
        });

        return manager;
    }
}
```

Please keep in mind that `User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()` is marked deprecated because of security-concerns.

Comment: Thx for your solution. I had problems because the class ApplicationClient and all values where null. Just added setters and getter to the ApplicationClient like described here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/configuration-metadata.html and now everything works find